# VBA and Aria HTML Control

Tags: vba

I have a seemingly simple but aggravating question. I am writing VBA code to control a slider bar on a webpage. This should be straightforward process like filling various types of check boxes and input boxes but I am running into a coding error. The slider bar has a high and low value that I would like to set (denoted by Price).

Here is my code...

```
Function Master
Dim Elem As Object      ' Object used in For loop.
Dim e As Object         ' Object used in For loop.
Dim Element As Object   ' Object used to click buttons for search.

Dim PriceLow As Integer
Dim PriceHigh As Integer

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objWindow = objShell.Windows()
Set Elem = objIEApp.Document.getElementsByTagName("div")
For Each e In Elem
    If e.role = "slider" And e.tabindex = 1 Then
        e.aria-valuenow = Pricelow
    ElseIf e.role = "slider" And e.tabindex = 2 Then
        e.aria-valuenow = Pricehigh
    End If
Next e
End Function
```

This is the HTML code for the low Price (without the <> brackets)

```
div
    tabindex="1" class="airslide-handle" role="slider" aria-valuenow="10"
    aria-valuemin="10" aria-valuemax="1000" style="left: 0%;" 
    data-reactid=".4.1.1:$0" abp="340" data-handle-key="0">
/div
```

And for the high Price (same with <>)

```
div tabindex="2" class="airslide-handle" role="slider" aria-valuenow="1000" 
    aria-valuemin="10" aria-valuemax="1000" style="left: 100%;"
    data-reactid=".4.1.1:$1" abp="341" data-handle-key="1">
/div
```

When I type in the code lines "e.aria-valuenow = Pricehigh" and "e.aria-valuenow = Pricelow" though, VBA auto edits to make my code "e. Aria - valuenow = Pricehigh" and "e.Aria - valuenow = Pricelow" which obviously causes a compiling error in VBA. How do I fix or get around this?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this instead of using the [`attributes`](http://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/prop_node_attributes.asp) collection or [`getAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: I run into the same problem by attempting to type "aria-valuenow" which turns into "Aria - valuenow" still causing the same compile error.

Answer (score 0):

just write "ariaValuenow " without the "-". So

```
If e.role = "slider" And e.tabindex = 1 Then
    e.ariaValuenow = Pricelow
ElseIf e.role = "slider" And e.tabindex = 2 Then
    e.ariaValuenow = Pricehigh
End If
```

Cheers